# How to change the PDF template regarding the language?

Tags: pdf, orbeon, formbuilder

In our forms we use a PDF template to print out the data. Works great. As we will have our forms available in 4 languages in orbeon, we would like to have 4 different PDF templates. The same template but in other languages, with orbeon choosing the right one depending on the currently chosen language.

How to achieve this ?

I use FormBuilder and the "Attach template" functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't currently supported out-of-the-box by Orbeon Forms. See [RFE #246](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/246).